# Create XSD from Java Class or from XML?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

What is the best way to get a XSD file to validate XML files in future, from Java Class or from Xml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.   It's best to create an XSD by careful deliberation by hand.

Automatically creating an XSD from an object or an XML document instance can be useful to jumpstart the process but cannot capture all constraints likely to be needed.  Consider that in general, a single member of a category rarely possesses sufficient characteristics to support basing the definition of the entire category on it alone.

Comment: But if I create a xsd file through a java class, the validation method will accept any xml file created through the same java class?

Comment: @Urbester No, because the constraints are not enforced, by default. E.g. `@XmlAttribute(required = true)` will still not generate the attribute if value is `null`, so it will fail validation when later doing a validating parse.